# Tethering a Windows XP laptop to a CentOS desktop

Tags: networking, centos, home-networking, windows-xp

I have a laptop running Windows XP Service Pack 3. There is a [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 6.0 desktop next to it. The Windows XP laptop has a Wi-Fi card, and it has Internet access. The CentOS computer does not have a Wi-Fi card or Internet access.

I don't want to purchase a wireless NIC for the desktop. What are the steps I can do to get an Internet connection from my Windows XP laptop to the CentOS desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You can link the two systems together with a switch or crossover cable and ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) should be possible on the wireless NIC which will share (NAT) its Internet connection.